# How to set padding/margin for Google +1 button in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, padding, margin, google-plus-one

http://healthybodyguru.com

If you load the site and wait 3 seconds you'll see the [attentionGrabber](http://attentiongrabber.tommasoraspo.com/) bar appear in the header.  It has shortcodes to add the social buttons (FB, Twitter, G+1), but for some reason the Google +1 button is too high.

I've tried adding custom CSS to lower it by adding margin/padding to the top but that didn't make a difference.

Any ideas what CSS I can use to make it line up with the other social buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add:

```
#attentionGrabberWrap .plusoneBtn iframe{
   margin-bottom: -3px !important;
}
```

I got help from the plugin creator :)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting:

```
#___plusone_0 {
    font-size: default; !important
}
```

Override inline CSS styles with [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules).

Comment: Thanks, but after adding that CSS when I inspect element in Chrome it's crossed out (not applied)

Comment: @kane see update. It's an inline styling so you'll have to override it by force.

Comment: Nope, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @kane You mean it's still crossed out? I modified the inline style on this element to font-size: default; in chrome developer tool and it fixed the problem.

Comment: It's not crossed out but the button is still in the same spot.  Also, why would the font-size have anything to do with margin/padding on top of the button?

Comment: I honestly don't know, and don't think I should, because `<div>` inside a `<span>` is invalid markup. The reason I posted the solution is because it fixed the problem when I changed `font-size: 1px` to `font-size: default` on `#___plusone_0` using Chrome devtools & firebug. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Don't worry about it paislee, I gave a working solution too, and he could not figure out how to implement it either.

Answer (score 1):

try putting a span tag around the google +1 button and pad that top.

```
<span style="padding-top:5px;">[shortcode]</span>
```

I don't know if you tried this with custom css but if not give it a shot and see what happens. a style tag in the html should override any styling that the stylesheet is giving the element.

Comment: Nope, doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see I like divs and not spans.  I've always gotten better results from divs than spans when css is playing around.

```
<div id="attentionGrabber">

  <div id="centeredPart" style="width: 575px; margin:0 auto">

    <div style="float:left;" class="facebookBtn">
      ...like code....
    </div>  

    <div style="float:left;" class="twitterBtn" >
      ...twitter code...
    </div>  

    <div style="float:left;" class="plusoneBtn">
      ...+1 code...
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;" class="linkToForums">
      Check out our new forums:
      <a class="link" href="http://healthybodyguru.com/forum/">go!</a>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

  </div> 

 <div id="closeAttentionGrabber"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but that just made it look real ugly.  The "Check out our new forums" text was below the pop-down bar immediately when the page loaded.  The "Like" and "Tweet" buttons were touching the top of the bar and the "+1" button again didn't move (it's getting sorta funny at this point that nothing can make it move).

Comment: That's strange, I put that code into my browser and it made it like what you had, but with google aligned with the other items.  I used firebug to edit the HTML real-time, and pasted the code from it here.

Answer (score 0):

I just put an invisible letter behind mine. A bit hacky but it worked for me.

```
<br><div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="none"></div><span style="font-size:33px;opacity:0;">G</span>
```